# using operator [] with a map in a const method

Tags: c++

say i have a method as this

```
int someclass::somemethod(const std::string &name) const
{
       std::string a = mymap["a"];
       ..... 
}
```

where mymap

```
std::map<std::string,std::string>
```

This is the error i get

```
Error   1   error C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::map<std::string, std::string>   ' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Any suggestions on how i can access value of a key ? ?

Comment: use map::find to get an iterator to the element.

Comment: It's good form to write a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) which has an example declaration of a map and the accessing of the map.

Comment: I know i could do that however for some crazyy reason the map is returning end() and I am certain the item is in the container. Thats why i wanted to use the [] operator

Comment: Using `operator[]` to do the search won't help. Either the names match (in which case `find` will work fine) or else they don't (in which case `[]` will insert a *new* node with the new key and a value-initialized mapped value--an empty string in this case).

Comment: @SamIam its not a complicated example. Create a method inside a class with const and test it out. What i gave here makes clear sense and on top of that i explicitly stated that this problem is because of a const mehtod

Comment: @Beginner: Not really, no.

Comment: @MistyD when asking a question it's up to you to provide the full example - help others to help you .  In this case it turns out that experienced answerers can identify a likely cause of error just based on the error message, but that's not always true; and the "most likely answer based on the error message" is not always the actual root of the problem.

Comment: @MistyD I'm not completely familiar with this problem and this problem might be able to be identified without a SSCCE, but there are many cases where users ask questions giving segmented code blocks(like you are) where the **real problem** exists **outside** of the provided code.  for future reference, it's normally a good idea to make one when the problem is this simple to reproduce.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit looks identical to me. OP didn't bother to show the actual code; perhaps the `map` in question is `const` by virtue of being a class member in a `const` function , or declared `const` (as opposed to coming in via a parameter), but the problem and solution are the same

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Mate the code's right there in the question. The map is `const` by virtue of being a class member in a `const` function, which is different from the question you linked to, ergo, not a "duplicate".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you seem to be assuming `mymap` is a member of `someclass`; this is not stated in the question.  IMO it is a duplicate despite this minor detail. To be marked "duplicate" it doesn't have to be word for word identical.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duplicate Cheers

Comment: good thing that thefreedictionary isn't in charge of SO site policy then eh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use map's `.find` member function to do the search.

```
auto it = mymap.find("a");

if (it != mymap.end())
    // it->first = key, it->second = mapped value.
```

Using `operator[]` instead of `find` won't make the search work any better. Either the keys match (in which case `find` will work just fine) or else they don't (in which case `[]` attempts to insert a new node with that key, which will be associated with a value-initialized value--an empty string in this case.

It's that latter behavior (inserting the new node) that means there's no `const` version of `operator[]`.

Yes, it would have been possible to define `operator[]` in a way that worked with a `const` container, such as throwing an exception when/if the requested key wasn't present--but it's not defined to work that way now, and *probably* won't be any time soon either.

Answer (score 6):

The `std::map::operator[]` has a (evil (!?)) non-constant side effect. The operator adds a new element if that element does not already exist. `somemethod()` is declared as `const`, so the `std::map` is also `const` and cannot be modified. Hence, the non-constant `operator[]` can not be applied to the `const std::map`. Alternatives are `std::map::find()` and `std::map::at()` (C++11).

Comment: `std::map::at()` might be a good alternative too.

Comment: @juanchopanza: yes, but only in C++11 and later.  Either way, `find()` returns an interator, which makes it easy to check if the element exists or not.  But `at()` throws a `std::out_of_range` if the elements does not exist.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's one before the current standard. We're in the year 2015 ;-)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, but may C++ compliers still do not support C++11 yet, or only support portions of it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, that could be an optional note in an answer. The question doesn't specify C++03, so I see no reason to restrict answers to old standards.

Comment: And I see no reason to restrict answers to brand new standards that you know full well are ill-supported in reality.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK, let's all pretend C++11 never happened then.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Who ever suggested doing that??!?!#